# 80% of sales out of Total sales in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this

```
Brand Name  Sales Cost  Mkt
Brand1  3312    ABC
Brand2  3490    ABC
Brand3  7794    ABC
Brand4  8325    ABC
Brand5  3915    ABC
Brand6  6494    ABC
```

Expected output should be like this:

```
Brand Name  Sales Cost  Mkt Percentage
Brand1  3312    ABC 10%
Brand2  3490    ABC 17%
Brand3  7794    ABC 80%
Brand4  8325    ABC 89%
Brand5  3915    ABC 12%
Brand6  6494    ABC 59%
```

I want to find out Brand that holds 80% sales in ABC market? Suggestions please

Comment: Basically what is the percentile of sales of particular brand out of all brands output will be like                                                                    Brand Name Sales Cost Mkt Percentage
Brand1 1849 ABC 10%
Brand2 4216 ABC 24%
Brand3 1395 ABC 85%
Brand4 7034 ABC 40%

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Its Just a random data, I want to calculate in the market ABC which all brands holds 80% of sales

Comment: Sorry for that, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want window functions. I'm assuming that `brandX` can occur more than once in your data for one `mkt` (even though you do not have such rows in your example)

```
select brand, 
       mkt,
       sum(sales), 
       sum(cast(sales as float))/sum(cast(sum(sales) as float)) over (partition by mkt) * 100 
from data
group by brand, mkt
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=89d7cd6803bd21df00b245ec6672c0bd)

and if you want those having more then 80% use subquery and where

```
select *
from
(
    select brand, 
           mkt,
           sum(sales) sumsales, 
           sum(cast(sales as float))/sum(cast(sum(sales) as float)) over (partition by mkt) * 100 percentsales
    from data
    group by brand, mkt
) t
where percentsales > 80
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * from (
select [Brand Name],
       [Sales],
       [Cost],
       [Sales]/(sum([Sales]) over (partition by (select null))) [Mkt Percentage]
from MY_TABLE
) [a] where [Mkt Percentage] >= 0.8
```